# IntelliSense: expression must have integral or enum type

Tags: c++, types, enums, expression, integral

Guys i need someone fix this problem ? when i compile that code i have this error:

```
 Error: IntelliSense: expression must have integral or enum type
```

i have problem in this part:

```
Console(0, V("seta sv_hostname " + servername + ";\n"));
```

so how i can fix that

```
if (strncmp(command, V("exec config_mp"), 14) == 0)
{
    if (GAME_MODE == 'D')
    {
        CIniReader iniReader(V(".\\teknogods.ini"));
        char *servername = iniReader.ReadString(V("Settings"),V("Servername"),"");

        if (strcmp(servername,"") == 0)
        {
            info("Server name set to defult.");
        }
        else
        {
            //Console(0, V("seta scr_teambalance 1;\n"));
            Console(0, V("seta sv_hostname " + servername + ";\n"));
            info("server name set to: %s.", servername);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to tag this with the appropriate language. C++ perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot concatenate two C strings with `+`.

In C and C++ string literals are arrays of characters, which when used as rvalue in an expression decay into a pointer to the character. In C (and C++) you can perform pointer arithmetic, which means that you can add or substract an integer (or any integral type) from a pointer and you can also substract two pointers to obtain a difference, but you cannot add two pointers together. The expression `"A" + "B"` is incorrect as that would try to add two `const char*`. That is what the compiler is telling you: for the expression `"seta sv_hostname " + servername` to be correct, `servername` must be either an integer or an enum.

If coding C++ you can use `std::string`, for which there are overloaded `operator+` that take either another `std::string` or `const char*` and then use the `c_str` member function to retrieve a `const char*` to use in interfaces that require C strings.

Comment: Thank you and can you tell me how i can convert servername to integer or an enum ?!!

Comment: @user1743737: You cannot convert a generic string to an integer and you don't want to do it either. You don't want pointer arithmetic, but string concatenation. If you want to concatenate strings, use `std::string` and then you can just concatenate: `std::string msg = "..."; msg += servername; msg += ";\n";`. To obtain a `const char*` you just call `c_str`: `msg.c_str()`. Now depending on what `Console` expects you might be able to pass a `std::string`, a `const char*` or neither of them... but without knowing the interface you use I cannot tell.